# HTML - PHP echo image

Tags: php, html

How do I properly echo images combining HTML and PHP? `$offer['picture']` has link saved as `example.com/picture.png`. I've tried many different options, but nothing works. Can anyone help me out?

```
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {
    $image = $offer['picture'];
    ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: Everything looks fine. Can you provide result output and expected output, please?

Comment: Result output is pretty much nothing, nothing is displayed. And expected outputs are displayed images from links stored in $offer['picture']. I'm not sure why it doesn't work, because if I do echo $offer['picture'], it gives all the links correctly. @Jakupov

Comment: share the arrays: `print_r($_json['offers']);` would be a good start

Comment: try to echo the $image variable first, is it returning the correct url of image?

Comment: Can you please provide me the data sample of $json['offers']
i need to check the sample and after that i will  write the script

Answer (score 1):

If there is only `example.com/picture.png` in `$offer['picture']`, problem is that images linked incorrectly. You should add `http://` before image link to make browser sure you are loading image by absolute path.

```
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {
    $image = $offer['picture'];
    ?>
    <img src="http://<?php echo $image ?>">
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: why should he use an absolute path? a relative one works well too

Comment: @LelioFaieta, OP has domain names in image urls. It will not work with relative url, unless images placed in subfolder, named like domain name which is unlikely.

Comment: actually the issue is that the php doesn't echo anything, so why should the http trailing solve his issue?

Comment: @LelioFaieta, OP mentioned, that just `echo $offer['picture']` works as expected. So, every part of code except image part works. Simple `img` tag cannot be `not working`, it's simple html. But it may not load images, if urls are incorrect. Some browsers do not replace missing images with icon, and `img` tag in example does not have `alt` attribute to show instead of images. So, visually there will be no output. As OP mentioned, there is example.com in variable, inserted as image source url, so adding `http://` should solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your directory structure.

suppose your images are in `example.com/assets/images/photo-1.jpg`

your code should be

```
<?php foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {
  $image = $offer['picture']; ?>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/assets/images/<?php echo $image; ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

In fact, you need to concatenate or hard code the path and image name will be appended dynamically.

Comment: why should OP use an absolute path? a relative one works well too

Answer (score -1):

Try this syntax,

```
<?php
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer) {
    $image = $offer['picture'];
    echo "<img src='$image' />";
}
?>
```